# SonarQube & Qt-based sources

Tags: c++, qt, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am novice user of SonarQube. 
I was tried to analyze some source CPP files through [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org) (with [sonar-cxx](https://github.com/wenns/sonar-cxx) plugin), these (source) files are contains of some QT code pieces (inheritance from QSharedData & a few QT macro), but in result I give a strange errors from SonarQube Runner:

```
08:28:13.903 WARN  - [D:\src\GrainBlitter\modules\CEDualString.h:3]: cannot find the sources for '#include <QSharedData>'
08:28:13.907 WARN  - [D:\src\GrainBlitter\modules\CEDualString.h:4]: cannot find the sources for '#include <QtGlobal>'
08:28:13.930 ERROR - Unable to parse file: D:\src\GrainBlitter\modules\CEDualString.cpp
08:28:13.933 ERROR - Parse error at line 3 column 39:

  -->  __classCCEDualString::CCEDualStringData: __publicQSharedData
    4: {
    5: __public:
    6:   CCEDualStringData() {}
    7:   CCEDualStringData( const CCEDualStringData& other ) : QSharedData( other ), m_ascii( other.m_ascii )

08:28:13.964 WARN  - [D:\src\GrainBlitter\modules\CEDualString.h:3]: cannot find the sources for '#include <QSharedData>'
08:28:13.969 WARN  - [D:\src\GrainBlitter\modules\CEDualString.h:4]: cannot find the sources for '#include <QtGlobal>'
08:28:13.987 ERROR - Unable to parse file: D:\src\GrainBlitter\modules\CEDualString.h
08:28:13.990 ERROR - Parse error at line 50 column 0:

   47: inline bool operator == ( const QString& l, const CCEDualString& r ) { return l == r.unicode(); }
   48:
   49: Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( CCEDualString )
  -->  Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( CCEDualStringsList )EOF

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 5.571s
Final Memory: 9M/118M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: COMMENT_BLANK_LINES
```

Properties file (sonar-project.properties) looks like:

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=GrainBlitter
sonar.projectName=GrainBlitter 0x01
sonar.projectVersion=0.0.xx

# Comma-separated paths to directories with sources (required)
sonar.sources=modules
#sonar.tests=UnitTests

# Language, needed for SonarQube < 4.2
sonar.language=c++
# Path to included files
sonar.cxx.include_directories=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/include,D:/Qt/qt-5.3.1-x64-msvc2012-opengl/qt-5.3.1-x64-msvc2012-opengl/include/,D:/Qt/qt-5.3.1-x64-msvc2012-opengl/qt-5.3.1-x64-msvc2012-opengl/include/QtCore

sonar.cxx.cppcheck.path=C:/Program Files (x86)/Cppcheck/cppcheck.exe

# Encoding of the source files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

# exclude qt created files
sonar.exclusions=**/ui_*.h
```

I specify QT include dir in [sonar.cxx.include_directories] variable, may be isn't correct? Please give me example of sonar-project.properties file with correct linkage to QT library. Thanks!
P.S. QSharedData header are included in my headers

Comment: partially fixed, configuration error in 'properties' file was found - sonar.cxx.include_directories - should be sonar.cxx.includeDirectories

Answer (score 1):

This is very likely due to the extension that qt made to the C++ language (which if I recall goes further than a few macros).

I don't know if sonar can handle this natively (or if there is a plugin) but as a first approach maybe you can run the analysis on the sources after they have been transformed by qt's preprocessor (moc).